# How does a variable definition work in assembly?

Tags: variables, assembly, static, nasm

The popular hello world program in assembly defines within the .data section the string "Hello, world!". According to this tutorial (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_variables.htm) db defines one byte (allocate one byte in memory).

```
    section .text
    global _start   ;must be declared for linker (ld)
_start:             ;tells linker entry point
    mov edx,len     ;message length
    mov ecx,msg     ;message to write
    mov ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel

    mov eax,1       ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel

section .data
msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ;our dear string
len equ $ - msg     ;length of our dear string
```

Does this mean one byte will be allocated for each character? When this is correct, then this line would allocate 14 Bytes (13 Bytes for "Hello, world!" and one byte for 0xa - right?

Comment: Yes. You can read about this in your assembler's manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Yes, in fact it does! It defines any amount of bytes, containing exactly what you give it.

---

There are three sections  that are commonly used in assembly programs. `.text`, `.data`, and `.bss`. The `.text` section is for, well, code, and can be read or executed from, but not written. `.data` is for your *initialized* (like `int a = 56` in C) variables. It is read and write, but no execute. `.bss` is for *uninitialized* (like `int a` in C) variables, and can be changed at runtime, and is zero initialized (instead of being initialized with a specific value). It has the same permissions as `.data`.

**The `.data` section is fine for Hello World, but prefer to use `.rodata` (windows is `.rdata`, thanks comments), as it is read only.**

Comment: `.code` is a Windows thing.  On Linux code goes in the `.text` section, like in the question which is also using Linux system calls.  The .text section and .rodata section get linked into read-only segments, with at least .text in an executable segment.

Comment: `.data` is for read/write data with non-zero initializers, like the BSS but with initializers.  C compilers use it for non-`const` global / static variables.  You're thinking of `.rodata` (non-Windows) or `.rdata` (Windows).  It's common for beginners to put string constants in `.data` along with mutable data but it's (usually) not optimal and not what compilers do.

Comment: `.bss` isn't "undefined" under modern mainstream OSes.  It's zero-initialized.

Comment: (The main point of this answer is correct, and I'd like to upvote it once you fix all the mistakes in details.  Agreed that asm doesn't have variables per-se, outside of MASM's magic; it's up to the programmer to use symbol labels + db pseudo-instructions to implement static variables.  Or registers for local variables.)

Comment: You took out the part about asm not truly having variables, and that being a high-level concept you have to implement yourself.  :(  Also, proofread your sentence about `.data` again.  It's not for "stuff that doesn't need to change".  Also I'd suggest a bullet list (`*` or `-` in markdown) fo talk about each standard section.  Also, you don't need to leave an "Edit:" message in your answer; that's what the changelog is for when you're saving your edit. And/or comment to reply to comments that pointed out things to change.